# LINQ join multiple tables on same column

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a table names TestNotifications which has a CompanyID and a TestCompanyID.  Those IDs link to a Companies table which has a companyName column.  I need to get the companyName for the company and testCompany.  The code below isn't working, I'm getting a cannot implicitly convert error.  Any help appreciated.

```
testNotifications = from t in db.CT_TestNotifications
    join c in db.CT_Companies on t.CompanyID equals c.CompanyID
    join tc in db.CT_Companies on t.TestCompanyID equals tc.CompanyID 
    select new
    {
        t.TestNotificationID,
        c.CompanyName,
        //tc.CompanyName
        TestCompanyName = tc.CompanyName
    };
```

Here is the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to
'System.Linq.IQueryable<CT_TestNotification>'. An explicit conversion exists 
(are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: The query looks OK... can you provide the stack trace, please?

Answer (score 3):

You're projecting into an anonymous type but `testNotifications` expects `CT_TestNotification`.

Try creating an instance of `CT_TestNotification` in your `select`:

```
testNotifications = from t in db.CT_TestNotifications
    join c in db.CT_Companies on t.CompanyID equals c.CompanyID
    join tc in db.CT_Companies on t.TestCompanyID equals tc.CompanyID
    select new CT_TestNotification       // Here's the major difference
    {
        PropName = t.TestNotificationID, // PropName must be changed to the
        PropName = c.CompanyName,        // properties of your actual class
        //tc.CompanyName
        TestCompanyName = tc.CompanyName
    };
```

Comment: If I do that, then it says CT_TestNotification does not contain a definition for the properties not in that table....

Answer (score 0):

See if your join on criteria are of the same types - IE is t.CompanyID an int and c.CompanyID.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue lies in how you declared testNotifications. If you did something like the following, you would see that error:

```
IQueryable<CT_TestNotifications> testNotifications;

testNotifications = from t in db.CT_TestNotifications 
    join c in db.CT_Companies on t.CompanyID equals c.CompanyID 
    join tc in db.CT_Companies on t.TestCompanyID equals tc.CompanyID  
    select new 
    { 
        t.TestNotificationID, 
        c.CompanyName, 
        //tc.CompanyName 
        TestCompanyName = tc.CompanyName 
    };
```

You would also get this same issue if you declared the testNotifications at the start and then continued with the query later on because you are trying to change the type of the value from the known type to an anonymous type.:

```
var testNotifications = db.CT_TestNotifications;
    testNotifications = from t in testNotifications 
        join c in db.CT_Companies on t.CompanyID equals c.CompanyID 
        join tc in db.CT_Companies on t.TestCompanyID equals tc.CompanyID  
        select new 
        { 
            t.TestNotificationID, 
            c.CompanyName, 
            //tc.CompanyName 
            TestCompanyName = tc.CompanyName 
        };
```

Since you are projecting an anonymous type, you need to use type inference and not explicitly declare the variable:

```
var testNotifications = from .. select ..;
```